# Using custom Model in Umbraco - error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco, models

I am getting the following error, when using my Custom model in Umbraco:

```
Cannot bind source type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel to model type MyParser.Model.MyModel.
```

The code, which contains this model, is an old project i am 'importing' into a Umbraco site - it used to be just a vanilla MVC app.

For my use, it does not need to interact with Umbraco or the database - it just needs to live in the same project.

The layout, calling the model, looks like this;

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<MyParser.Model.MyModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

The Model looks like this

```
namespace MyParser.Model
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The code works fine in the vanilla MVC app, but needs to be modified to run inside an Umbraco-app it would seem - but how?
It is Umbraco 7.6

Comment: Is it a partial view, doc type template?

Comment: Its a doc type template / layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a document type template, you need to hijack the route to inject the view model. You create the controller that inherits from `RenderMvcController` and override `Index` method.

```
namespace Controllers
{
    public class [YourDocTypeAlias]Controller : RenderMvcController
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {
            var vm = new ViewModel<MyModel>(model);
            return View(vm);
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel<TModel> : RenderModel
    {
        public ViewModel(RenderModel model) : base(model.Content, model.CurrentCulture) { }

        public TModel CustomModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and your template now becomes.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ViewModel<MyModel>>
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
    //you can now access properties from MyModel like Model.CustomModel.IsValid...
}
```

More info can be found on this [link](https://umbraco.com/blog/a-practical-example-of-route-hijacking-in-umbraco/).

Comment: I have not created a specific DocType for this alone - it just uses a Generic "Contentpage" DocType, that is also used for "normal" Umbraco pages. I just assigned the page to a layout file (the above)


Should i create a custom DocType for it?

Comment: Yes, you should create a custom DocType and hijack the route for that document type.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got that working - thank you. But.. do i then need to move my entire model inside the "YourViewModel" class? My project structure, includes 2 projects. The first project is the Umbraco site itself. The second project, is the model from the "imported" project, ie "namespace MyParser.Model".. do i need to move all that into the above class, or?

Comment: In this case, all your view models need to inherit from RenderModel so you would have to move your model inside ViewModel. But you can create a generic view model that inherits from RenderModel and use that without moving your models.

Comment: I think i am getting closer :-) Only error i am getting now, is that in my 2 project, my model, i have the following: public MyModel GetDataAsMyModel(ParserSettings settings)
        {
            var model = new MyModel();
 }

This is now updated to

public MyViewModel GetDataAsMyModel(ParserSettings settings)
        {
            var model = new MyViewModel();
 }

and i fails saying "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'model' of 'MyViewModel.MyViewModel(RenderModel)'

Comment: Check my edit, I made it generic so you don't have to move your models.

Comment: I now get this error: 'CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type '_MyNamespace.Controllers.ViewModel<MyParser.Model.MyModel>' to 'MyParser.Model.MyModel''

Comment: nvm - think i found a solution, was just me fidling around. Thank you the help - much appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe did not fix it quite.. i am now seeing this error 'Cannot bind source type MyExternalNamespace.Model.MyModel to model type _MyLocalNamespace.Controllers.ViewModel`1[[MyExternalNamespace.Model.MyModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].'

Comment: Moved it into a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427732/umbraco-custom-model-causing-problems

Comment: For anyone finding this question but using Umbraco v8, not v7.6 (OP), RenderModel should be replaced with ContentModel